# Gulp Glob Error on Src()

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm banging my head with what should be a simple fix to a gulpfile that would allow it to build scss files.

I have the following structure in my angular2 project:

`|-rootDir
|-- app
|--- <bunch of stuff in the app dir>
|-- resources
|--- scss
|---- <scss files>`

However, whenever I run `gulp create`I get an error stating `Error: Invalid glob argument: undefined`

What am I doing wrong here???

This is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
concat = require('gulp-concat'),
debug = require('gulp-debug'),
del = require('del'),
insert = require('gulp-insert'),
fs = require("fs");

/* Tasks Functions */
sass = function(files, dest) {
    pipe_files = gulp.src(files);

    return pipe_files
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
}

/* CSS Tasks */
gulp.task( 'styles', function() { sass( ['./resources/scss/*.scss'], './resources/css_gulp/') });

gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
    del(['./resources/css_gulp/*.*'], cb)
});

gulp.task( 'create', function() {
    gulp.start('styles');
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
    gulp.start('create');
});
```

So, where am I going wrong on the paths?

*** EDIT ***
I've added gulp-debug and this is the output:
`[20:03:40] Finished 'create' after 17 ms
[20:03:40] gulp-debug: resources/scss/main.scss
[20:03:40] gulp-debug: resources/scss/prime-overrides.scss
[20:03:40] gulp-debug: 2 items`

Everything seems correct here. So why the error?

Comment: I don't think that the sass function take the array of paths. AFAIK you shoud pass an object with a property `includePaths` that is the array of paths.

Comment: Hmm I'll look into that but I think that is a recent change maybe? On my other project where I use gulp I have it set up exactly like this and it is working

Comment: You're redefining `sass`.

Comment: Jesus it's always the stupidest things that get me making this kind of questions.. *sigh* Please promote that to an answer and I'll mark it as correct. That was indeed the issue :palmface:

Comment: @SvenSchoenung got it!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Sven in comment. The issue seems to be caused due to defining the task function "sass".

Changing the function name would solve it.

I have seen similar errors with src() function before especially when mainBowerFiles dependency is loaded but not called properly in gulp.src()

It would be easier to identify such issues if as a principle we write the entire callbacks separately and also ensuring that String or Array of glob getting passed.

```
gulp.task('myTask', myTaskCallback);

// myTaskCallback implementation

function myTaskCallback() {
  return gulp.src() // ensure Glob or array of globs to read.
    .pipe()......
}
```

More can be found in the gulp documentation.
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v3.9.1/docs/API.md